# How to learn cryptography

Tags: reference-request, cryptography, online-resources

I have just started learning Cryptography.I looked on the Wikipedia and found topics like "Public key Cryptosystem","Symmetric Cryptography" ,"Cryptanalysis" etc.

Below this in the reference section there are enumerous papers .I just wonder if there are any books available in this section which will deal with the topics mentioned above .

Also what are the prerequisites in learning this subject?

Please help me in finding some good books in this subject.

Comment: Wouldn't crypto.SE be a better place for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.math.com.mx/docs/cur/cur_1_002_Criptografia.pdf) you can find information (in spanish) about cryptography and matrix algebra.

Comment: I use to use cryptography for my Software. look for md5 and sha1

Answer (score 0):

May be you can start the subject by reading the book by Prof. Douglas R Stinson. Here is the link. https://www.crcpress.com/Cryptography-Theory-and-Practice-Third-Edition/Stinson/9781584885085.